# How do I initialise a Pointer to a Object inside a std::array (container)?

Tags: c++, arrays, containers

I have this array:

```
std::array<dto_s, nQ> Q;
```

And want to have another array of pointers on objects in Q.
(represents the delta function of a DFA)

How do I initialise the array?

My question is about: Whats the data Type of Objects inside a array?

This doesn't work:

```
std::array<dtos,nQ> deltafunction[nDelta];
```

Comment: You say you want an "array of pointers on objects in Q". The "objects in Q" is of type `dto_s`, and if you want an array of pointers to that then you want an array of `dto_s*`. Basically `std::array<dto_s*, whatever_size_you_need>`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the type of these objects is `dto_s*` (or `dtos*`, you used two different spellings). In your initilization code, you mix `std::array` with C-style arrays (the `[nDelta]`). If you want an array of pointers, use

```cpp
std::array<dto_s*,nDelta> deltafunction;
```

(assuming `nDelta` is your number of pointers needed). If you need an array of array of pointers (i.e. an array for each object in `Q`, your code implies) you should not mix these two types of arrays but use

```cpp
std::array<std::array<dto_s*, nDelta>, nQ> deltafunction
```

But please be exceedingly careful with pointers on members of an array. If you copy both arrays, the elements of the copy of `Q` will be on new positions but the pointers in the copy of `deltafunction` will still be pointing at the elements of `Q`. There is a high risk for errors here. I advise you to not you use pointers as identification of the elements of `Q` but instead reference them by their index in `Q`.

Especially if you at some point change your code from `std::array` to `std::vector` it is risky, since a `std::vector` can be reallocated (in other words the elements can be moved to new positions) simply if you add a new element.